# Software to calculate the speed of objects in videos

Tags: gratis, open-source, video

I am looking for a software which allows me to find the velocity, acceleration etc. of objects in a given video. The software should be able to give the results in a graph and also the obtained results in a table.

Answer (score 6):

[Tracker](http://physlets.org/tracker/) is an excellent software which allows you to do this. Once you have selected a reference distance, the software will automatically generate the velocity and acceleration tables for you. It is free and available for Windows, Linux and Mac OSx. The software has an auto tracker feature that can detect moving objects automatically. A video tutorial on how to use the tool is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dn0Zz7rtkZw).

[image]